# What is the best way to manage an Apache Virtualhost vonfiguration?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I want a customer to manage his virtualhosts on his own. This should be done by some kind of web interface, where even someone without much technical expertise can manage it.
I was looking into the vhost_hash_alias module, but this does not allow me to define aliases easily (`domain.com` and `www.domain.com` should point into the same folder).

Any suggestions what is best to use?

Answer (score 1):

What about webmin? You can create a user with permissions to Apache configuration only.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reselling web hosting, you might want to look into a commercial control panel solution, such as Plesk, cPanel or similar.  These allow you to delegate permissions in a far more granular manner than most sysadmin-oriented tools.